# Python functions prototype in Opencv Library

Tags: python, opencv

`cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) → dst`

I am trying to understand , what arguments this function takes, and for that I am reading this page http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and

It says this function takes following arguments

- src1 array
- src2 array
- des array
- mask [optional]

But, I don't understand the representation of this function, like,why the function arguments in square brackets and also , position of commas is confusing. Please explain .

Comment: Whilst they do not state it in their documentation, by convention square brackets indicate optional fields/parameters

Comment: in this only mask is optional, so shouldn't it be cv2.bitwise_and(src1,src2,dst,[mask]) → dst  ??

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for this library does not seem to specify the formal syntax used as far as I can see however many developers will recognise the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message) of using square brackets to denote optional fields/parameters.

If we follow this convention and then break down the definition they have provided:

`cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) → dst`

This says that the function `bitwise_and` takes `src1` and `src2` as input unconditionally.  `dst` appears inside a `[...]` block which indicates it is optional.  The `mask` parameters appears as *another* optional block nested inside the `dst` optional block which suggests that, not only is it optional but it is only relevant if we have previously specified `dst` in the outer block.

So this documentation suggests that the following are all valid inputs:

```
cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2)
cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2, dst)
cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2, dst, mask)
```

But suggests that this would be invalid (in some undefined way):

```
cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2, mask)
```

However if we look at the *actual* Python function definition it is as follows:

```
def bitwise_and(src1, src2, dst=None, mask=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """ bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst[, mask]]) -> dst """
    pass
```

Now we can clearly see that both `dst` and `mask` are optional (both default to `None`).  Strictly speaking we could supply `mask` without supplying `dst` but the documentation is *hinting* to us that it will not be used if `dst` is not specified.

**Speculation**: I'm not at all familiar with this library but I would guess that `dst` is optional as if not supplied the output will be returned from the function instead.  If so it may be that `mask` can in fact be provided independent of `dst` and if so I would argue that the a better documentation string would have been:

```
cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2[, dst][, mask]) → dst
```

But again as there is no formally defined syntax for the documentation it is open to interpretation and speculation.